# Automatically open specified domains in different browsers

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, default-browser

I use mainly two browsers on my Ubuntu 18.04 and use them for different websites, ie. logged into my google account in my Chrome browser however not in Firefox; also I use different add-ons for the same websites in my browsers. Firefox is my default browser. However, is there a way to specify certain domains to automatically open in specific browsers? I want all Google-related websites to open in Chrome plus a few others where I am logged in (often, but not always, via my Google ID).

Ideally this solution should work wherever I am in Ubuntu, so all applications; though the priority is e-mail clients.

If not, is there a way to have a right-click context menu item enabling choice of browsers?

Thanks in advance for your kind help!

Max

Comment: See if http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=1081175 and https://www.ghacks.net/2012/02/15/how-to-turn-chrome-or-firefox-into-a-single-site-browser/ offer any hints.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Unfortunately they do not help. What I am looking for is an automated workflow for what is currently the following actions: thoughtful consideration then a right-click, copying the link, switching to the proper app/browser, opening a new tab, inserting copied link, hitting enter. That “thoughtful consideration” really seems to be the trickiest part—typically I click much faster than I think :)